# iOS unit tests failing with invalid XCTest bundle errors on M1

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

When running unit tests on an M1 machine a number of bundle errors are being generated and are crashing the test suite immediately.

Specifically:

- Failed to load test bundle
- No suitable image found
- Trying to load an unsigned library

```
2021-11-04 08:53:33.378375-0600 xxx[81944:1274939] Failed to load test bundle from file:///Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit%20Tests.xctest/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests: code signature in (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests: code signature in (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library, NSBundlePath=/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “Unit Tests.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
2021-11-04 08:53:33.683690-0600 xxx[81944:1274939] The bundle “Unit Tests.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2021-11-04 08:53:33.683757-0600 xxx[81944:1274939] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests: code signature in (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices/FDCD6684-3D06-48C9-81E3-DE82C6AB2CCB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7143E7F2-E59A-4578-971A-A2A20D42DDB6/xxx.app/PlugIns/Unit Tests.xctest/Unit Tests) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library)
```

The same unit tests run as expected on an Intel-based Mac.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there was a subtle warning being generated that lead to the solution.

[image]
In the unit test target's build settings, under Packaging, if you turn on "Generate Info.plist File" or manually specify an Info.plist, this fixes the issue.

[image]

Comment: I did not even get this warning; still, this solution fixed the problem for me. Thanks a lot!!